# Sql table query for tables with no direct link

Tags: sql

I have `Table_A` that has a column: 'FullName',columnB, .. and other columns

I have `Table_B` that has columns: 'FirstName', 'LastName','Job_OID'

Evidently, If we join the characters of `FirstName` and `LastName`, it matches `Full_Name`.

This is the only thing common between these two tables!

Problem: When the Full Name is "John Smith" in Table_A, I want to fetch his Job_OID from table_B.

In simple language,
select job_oid from table_B where ('FirstName' + 'LastName') = Table_A.FullName;

Comment: What's wrong with your query? Maybe just concatenate a space in the join and refer to the fields themselves, not strings:   `where (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) = Table_A.FullName;`  It's certainly far from optimal, but given the data, this is probably the best you have to aim for.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some non-ANSI SQL there.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT job_oid 
FROM table_B 
JOIN Table_A ON Table_A.FullName = Table_B.FirstName+' '+TableB.LastName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write query in this way:

```
SELECT B.job_oid 
FROM Table_A  A
INNER JOIN table_B  B ON A.FullName = CONCAT(B.FirstName, ' ', B.LastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must normalize your DB, but if it isn't possible, you can write following query:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM Table_B B
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 'PERSON'
    FROM Table_A A
    WHERE B.FirstName + ' ' + B.LastName = A.FullName)
```

You can use, otherwise, `JOIN` command like this:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM Table_B B
JOIN Table_A A
    ON B.FirstName + ' ' + B.LastName = A.FullName
```

So, in this way you link two tables with a concatenation of two fields (FirstName and LastName of Table_B) with FullName stored in Table_A